# I need to know for sure if binary 64bit supports any 32-bit static libraries or not.?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, static-libraries

I'm trying to figure out if I'm using 32-bit static library support in my target/local repo.
Although my architecture is 64-bit, my local repository contains a mixture of 32-bit (static, shared) and 64-bit (static, shared) libraries as well as binaries (32/64-bit).
I was able to extract the shared library list (32-bit and 64-bit) from binary using the ldd command, but I was unable to do so for static libraries because they are created at compilation time and do not have the same linking functions or symbols.

How can I tell in my repository whether a 64-bit binary contains a 32-bit static library?

In my repo linux machine, I've tried nm and readelf, but the nm program is missing from the target.

Comment: By definition 64-bit binary may not contain 32-bit binaries. Of course with some dirty tricks it can be done, but beleive me, in 99.999% cases that you may have, there is no such thing.

Comment: Similarly, 64-bit binaries cannot load 32-bit shared libraries.